# Node dynamic export and top level await on single file environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

There are cases when I'm doing I'm working on a single js file environment, for example Grease Monkey scripts, and I would like to add a node test runner (mocha). Js is very flexible and allows to handle both environments. Doing something like:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = {
    myFunctionToTest
  }
} else {
   // Code to be executed in the real environment
}

function myFunctionToTest () {

}
```

This approach is nice in that I can simply write tests in mocha in another file:

```
const {myFunctionToTest} = require('./source.js')

describe('My test', // ...
```

But also I can copy paste the script to the single js environment.

The problem that I'm facing is that I want to do a similar thing in an environment that allows top level await. If I try to do the previous example, I get a SyntaxError `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. Of course, node allows top level await with the flag `--experimental-top-level-await`, but that requires the code to be in module mode. And module mode does not allow module.exports.

Is there a way in module mode to do dynamic exports to avoid syntax problems in other js environments? Or to avoid await syntax errors in branches of the code that are not executed?

Answer (score 0):

A poor man's solution is to fake the bundler:

```
let functionToTest
beforeEach(async function () {
  const moduleCode = fs.readFileSync('./myscript.js').toString()
  const myFunctionCode = `async function myFunction (module) { ${moduleCode}}`
  eval(myFunctionCode)
  const fakeModule = {}
  await myFunction(fakeModule)
  functionToTest = fakeModule.exports.functionToTest
})
```